# ScrollView with position absolute is not scrolling in android [react native]

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, react-native, scrollview

I want to make dropdown view using scrollview in react native, but scrollview is not scrolling in android while its position is absolute, in IOS it is scrolling like a charm.

This is my code

```
   <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', zIndex: 1 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.contryCode}
            onPress={()=>setVisible(prev=>!prev)}
        >
            <Text style={styles.selectedCode}>{code}</Text>
            <Icon name={visible ? 'up' : 'down'} size={15} color='#000' />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {visible ? <CodeList /> : null}
    </View>
```

```
const CodeList = () => {
    return (
        <ScrollView
            style={styles.codeList}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        >
            {codes.map((item: any, index: number) => {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() =>     handleSelectCountry(item?.phonecode)}>
                        <Text style={styles.codeText}>{item.phonecode}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                );
            })}
        </ScrollView>
    )
 }
```

I also tried wrapping `Scrollview` with `posotion:'relative'` in a `View` with `position:'absolute'`, but it did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the ScrollView in a View like this:

```js
const CodeList = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.codeListContainer}>
            <ScrollView
                style={styles.codeList}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            >
                {codes.map((item: any, index: number) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => handleSelectCountry(item?.phonecode)}>
                            <Text style={styles.codeText}>{item.phonecode}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                })}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    codeListContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 50,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        maxHeight: 200,
        overflow: 'scroll',
    },
    codeList: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 10,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
    },
    // ... other styles
})
```

Comment: I already tried it, and also mentioned in my question

Comment: Did you also try it together with `overflow: 'scroll'`?